# Can you make ice red hot?

Tags: heat, popular-science, induction, ice

[This video clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLwaPP9cxT4) allegedly shows an otherwise unspecified ice cube that turns red hot (and burns) due to induction heating.

Can somebody explain how this works?

Comment: I recommend that you not try this at home.  The red hot metal can produce high temperature steam.  If that steam bubble gets trapped inside the ice cube, pieces of ice could go flying at significant speed once the steam pressure gets high enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The video was taken at the the EMO (which translates as "Machine Tool World Exposition") in Hannover at the booth of the company Huettinger. They have a [video on their website](http://www.huettinger.com/en/solutions/multimedia.html) where they show how its done: As already suspected, there is a metal piece inside the ice that is heated via induction. Towards the end of the video you can see that the glow comes from the red-hot metal, not from the ice itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a magic trick. Maybe the ice is actually housing a metallic substance which is being heated by induction. I'm no expert, as you may have deduced, but creating those kinds of currents and passing that current through a block of ice and seeing it become red hot? Something tells me this is an intelligent trick

Comment: Or it's magnets. I know it makes no sense in the context but every magic trick, illusion or stunt ever done is magnets.

Comment: Where did you hear that!? xD

Comment: From some drunk guy at a magic show once who couldn't figure out how any of the tricks were being done so just repeatedly shouted "It's magnets!" at the magician.

Comment: Not much of an answer. But funny comments. (about magnets.)....

Comment: @dimension10 thank you; but I though the answer was actually informative, I called the metal inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature = energy of molecular motion. Higher temperature = higher motion. At some point, known as melting point, kinetic energy of molecules becomes so strong that crystal forces cannot keep the molecules together and crystal desintegrates.

Because temperature destroys the crystallic structure, you cannot have temperature of ice be higher than its melting point. Since red-hot implies higher temperature, we can say that red-hot (> 100°C) ice is impossible. Might be they have some parts of the ice body evaporating while the rest is still at low temperatures.

Actually metal is also a crystal and you can have it red-hot. But, in your case you mean temperatures higher than melting points. You actually ask can we have cold warm? Cold heat is an [oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron). What you ask is "Do oxymorons exist?"

Might be it was inductive but not heating. Heating means "increased temperature". Increased temperature must cause ice melting. If this does not happen, we did not have the any heating.

Answer (score -2):

the magnet heats the metal which then melts the ice and makes it look like its glowing red hot.

Comment: This might be a better answer if you expanded on some of the details, rather than the short statement you have.

Answer (score -2):

Glass cube..illusion.

Metal inside ice heated red would melt boil vaporize explode an ice cube.

The illusioned water basen is moted around and below, separate from the Glass cube, as contact would cause Boiling, effecting the illusion.